# Confusing Diskutil List result?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I have a macbook pro with a 250 GB SSD in it. The diskutil list command gives a confusing result for me. It somehow shows a 98 GB disk. Does anyone know what this is? The result is pasted below. (also attached as screenshot)

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            98.0 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 19.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                518.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 'df -h' does this show about 98GB used on your hard drive?  APFS uses a container and volumes within that container that grow as needed.  What you see in 'diskutil list' is the size of the various APFS volumes rather than the containers.  E.g:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            269.6 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 86.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Mojave Beta             38.7 GB    disk1s5


MacBook:~ rhe$ df -lh
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5  466Gi   37Gi  173Gi    18%  819616 9223372036853956191    0%   /
/dev/disk1s4  466Gi  3.0Gi  173Gi     2%       3 9223372036854775804    0%   /private/var/vm
/dev/disk1s1  466Gi  251Gi  173Gi    60% 1767851 9223372036853007956    0%   /Volumes/Macintosh HD
```

Comment: Nope, All I see is this:

https://image.ibb.co/enxgNJ/Screen_Shot_2018_07_03_at_07_07_22.png

Comment: Hi, exactly -- your used space is 91GB, which is near enough to 98GB for these purposes.  You have a 250GB disk, your primary partition (now called a volume), "Macintosh HD" can grow to 250GB if needed, but at the moment, APFS is keeping the rest spare in case you want to add another volume on the same disk (container) and so it is sized at 98GB. It grows without you needing to do anything. In short, it's nothing to worry about.